# Dead keys not enabled, can't set them via system settings

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I've recently installed xubuntu 16.10 and the dead keys of my spanish keyboard are not working.

I've tried a couple of alternatives using `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and the system layout is set to `layout: latam` which is almost correct but dead keys are not working and I can't use the right tildes.

Using xfce's proper system configuration tool doesn't make any difference.

What else can I try?

Comment: Can you please enter a guest session and let us know if the problem is present there too.

Comment: yes, it's also present in the guest session.